# objective c regex starts with 1 or 2 digits

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa, nspredicate

I need the regex formula for 
ex "**17% off** etc etc"
or "**2% off** etc etc etc"
so if the string starts with a one or 2 digit number followed by the percent sign, space, and the word 'off'

I tried

```
NSPredicate* test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", @"^[0-9]{1,2}% off"];
if ( [test evaluateWithObject:candidate] )
{
.... etc..
```

but no luck.

I appreciate any insight.

Comment: I had no problem to match "23% off" or "7% off". Are your candidates in the right shape?

Comment: yes.. I made sure they start with the digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this command line example app it works just fine.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSArray *lines = @[ @"17% off etc.", @"2% off", @"off by 12%" ];
        NSPredicate* test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", @"^[0-9]{1,2}% off.*"];

        [lines enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString  *candidate, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if ( [test evaluateWithObject:candidate] ){
                NSLog(@":)");
            } else{
                NSLog(@":(");
            }
        }];


    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
2012-08-08 15:46:16.213 regextest[1305:303] :)
2012-08-08 15:46:16.215 regextest[1305:303] :)
2012-08-08 15:46:16.215 regextest[1305:303] :(
```

---

If the line contains more chars, it should look like

```
NSPredicate* test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", @"^[0-9]{1,2}% off.*"];
```

the `.*` indicates, that any number of any char might be present.

Comment: oh yes.. I forgot to end it. thanks a lot vikingosegundo! works

Comment: «Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.» RegEx is a bitch…